# How to execute cucumber java tests from command line interface

Tags: cucumber-jvm

I have written cucumber test cases using java. The location of my .feature file is:

```
Z:\eclipse\myworkspace\ProjectName\src\test\resources\GoogleLogin\test\GoogleLogin.feature
```

And location of my Step Definition files is:

```
Z:\eclipse\myworkspace\ProjectName\src\test\java\GoogleLoginStepDef\test\StepDefinitionGoogleLogin.java.
```

I am able to execute my test cases using Maven but no idea of execution through command line interface.

Could you please help me out with step by step process of executing cucumber java test cases from command line interface ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
java -cp "${LIB_DIR}/*" cucumber.api.cli.Main --glue ${GLUE_CODE} ${FEATURES_DIR} --format
```

Comment: Thanks Mark for your response. As I am new in command line interface so could you please verify whether below command is correct or not:                                                                                                       java -classpath jars/* cucumber.api.cli.Main --glue D:\eclipse\myworkspace\GoogleLogin\src\test\java\GoogleLoginStepDef\test\StepDefinitionGoogleLogin.java D:\eclipse\myworkspace\GoogleLogin\src\test\resources\GoogleLogin\test\GoogleLogin.feature

Answer (score 0):

Or try this one

```
 alias cucumber='java -cp "${LIB_DIR}/*" cucumber.api.cli.Main --glue ${GLUE_CODE} ${FEATURES_DIR} --format'
```

the you can fire up

```
$ cucumber
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can also use below command :**

```
java -Xmx1024m -cp '*' org.junit.runner.JUnitCore 'com.xx.automation.cucumber.testSuites.RunFeature’
```

This Your E.g:

```
java -Xmx1024m -cp '*' org.junit.runner.JUnitCore 'featureFilePath’
```